# How to fetch only one data from a database in a simple way?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my project, I use PDO to connect DB, and i fetch A data。

The result just like:

```
A

John
```

I have four statements to fetch it, the code is :

```
    $sql=" select A  from IDC where stSrv='$prdSty' and diffLvl='easy';";
    $sel=$conn->query($sql);
    $row=$sel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    $respTm=$row[0];
```

I think it is four sentences which is ugly and complicated.

Is there other simple and clear method to fetch data from DB?

Comment: is that less complicated? and easier to read? : `$rowTm=$conn->query(select A  from IDC where stSrv='$prdSty' and diffLvl='easy';)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)[0];` My opinion: no.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
$respTm =$conn->query(" select A  from IDC where stSrv='$prdSty' and diffLvl='easy';")
    ->fetchColumn();
```

But sticking together statements like this isn't always the best practice.

I find it easier to debug and maintain code that is separated into multiple lines like the example in your question.

For example, if you need to use a debugger and set a breakpoint after the query has been executed but before you fetch results, how can you do it?